# Swagger-codegen server stub for Node.js, user/client authentication implementation

Tags: node.js, authentication, swagger-codegen

I am using the swagger-codegen embedded in the swagger-editor to generate the server stub for Node.js.

After customizing the generated `.js` files and running them successfully, I am adding `basic` and `oauth2` based user/client authentication support for the server. After adding the security specifications via the swagger-editor, I noticed that, besides the `api/swagger.yaml` file, all of the other generated files were the same and no new files were generated for the changes.

Does it mean the generated Node.js server stub (including the swagger-tools package it uses) does not provide any user/client authentication capabilities?  If that is the case, do I need to make any changes to the `swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware()` statement in the generated `index.js` when my user/client authentication code is added to the file?